# SP 2016 Enterprise - Article page not displaying all content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, publishing-page

I have an article page with the body only layout. The only fields are the Title and Page Content fields. The Page Content field was only displaying a document library web part.

I edited the page to add some rich text content before the web part.

When I preview the page, it shows the rich text content and the web-part. When I save or check in the page, the rich text content is not displayed. Edit the page, all the content is visible.

I don't see anything odd in the HTML/source. This is not happening on every article page in the site collection, only a few.

Removing all content and re-adding it does not resolve the problem. When removing all content, I validate that there is no HTML/source remaining.

At this point, when there is only rich text content in the Page Content field, the rich text content does not display when saved or checked in.

How can I fix this article page?

Answer (score 0):

Did the issue only occur in the “article page with the body only” page layout?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Create a new page based on the “article page with the body only” page layout to check if the same issue.
2. Create the new page layout based on the “article page with the body only” page layout and create a new page based on the new page layout.

If the issue does not occur in the new page, you could consider moving the content from the problematical page to the new page.

Comment: I have tried creating a new page with the same layout. Same issue occurs.  Due to corporate lock-downs, I am unable to create a new page layout. IT requires funding to create new page layouts, so I would like to avoid that if possible.